# Initializing java.math.BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

Sorry cause this might look like a stupid yes or no question but I'm very new to this so I need an answer.

```
BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
```

and

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("0");
```

Are they the same?

Comment: You could call the `equals` method to find out whether these two objects are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a look at the documentation for both the [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf(long)) and the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

> **public static BigInteger valueOf(long val)**
> Returns a BigInteger whose value is equal to that of the specified long. This "static
> factory method" is provided in preference to a (long) constructor
> because it allows for reuse of frequently used BigIntegers.
>
> *Parameters:*   val - value of the BigInteger to return.
> *Returns:*   a BigInteger with the specified value.
>
> **BigInteger(String val)**
> Translates the decimal String representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger.

They both end up with a reference to a `BigInteger` with a value as `0`.

1. The `valueOf` is static, so you don't have to create an object in order to get the value.
2. If you call the constructor, then you do get a new object each time.

Answer (score 10):

They both end up with a reference to a `BigInteger` with a value of 0, but they're not identical in effect. In particular, as `valueOf` is a static method, it can make use of caching, and return the same reference if you call it twice:

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
System.out.println(a == b); // true on my machine
```

That doesn't appear to be *guaranteed*, but it's certainly *somewhat expected* given the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf-long-):

> Returns a `BigInteger` whose value is equal to that of the specified long. This "static factory method" is provided in preference to a (long) constructor because it allows for reuse of frequently used BigIntegers.

When you call the constructor, you really will get a new instance every time.

That said, for this particular example, I'd just use `BigInteger.ZERO`...

Comment: @ScaryWombat He addressed that on the second-to-last line.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Where do you get that impression from? I see nothing to indicate that. The OP asked whether two pieces of code were "the same" - I demonstrated what's the same between the two, and what's different between the two.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in this case, they are the same (if by "same" you mean "instances that are equal"), and you could also say `BigInteger.ZERO`.

But in the case of really big numbers you can only use the String constructor:

```
new BigInteger("12345678901234567890123456789012345")  // too long for long
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
                BigInteger i1 = new BigInteger("0");
                System.out.println(i==i1);//false
                System.out.println(i.equals(i1));//true
```

Comment: Note that you'd get the same result if you replace the first line with `BigInteger i = new BigInteger("0");`. It's really when you compare the references returned by two calls to `BigInteger.valueOf(0)` that the difference becomes noticeable. I also note that this is code-only answer with zero explanation, which is less than helpful...

Answer (score 1):

Lets do a quick experiment:

```
@Test
public void testBigIntegers() {
    assertThat(BigInteger.valueOf(0), is(new BigInteger("0")));
}
```

So, to be precise: you have two **equal** BigInteger objects here. 
As the BigInteger constructor only allows for entering "whole" integers; that is true for all values that valueOf() would be able to give you.

But because those two objects are created in different ways, you really have **two** different objects here. Whereas calling valueOf(0) twice might very well give the **same** object (reference) for both calls.

Comment: That says the two pieces of code produce references to equal objects. That's not the same as saying the two pieces of code are the same, or equivalent.

Comment: Updated my answer.